# Hash to CSV/TSV conversion in Perl

Tags: perl, csv, hash, export-to-csv

I'm trying to convert a simple hash to CSV/TSV in Perl. Now, the tricky part is that I'm unable to use `Text::CSV::Slurp` due to some funny reason, and I'm left with using `Text::CSV_XS` and `Text::CVS`.

Problem Description:

I am able to create a CSV file from the hash that I have, but display of the values isn't how I would desire them to be.

Example:

This is how my hash looks like:

```
`$VAR1 = {
          '2015-12-09 10:49:00' => '750 mW',
          '2015-12-09 10:49:02' => '751 mW'
        };`
```

I would want keys to be under one tab and values to be under another tab. Instead, I get a CVS which has everything in a comma-separated state.

Desired Output:

```
key1   value1
key2   value2
```

Actual Output:

```
key1  value1   key2   value2
```

This is how my code looks like as of now:

```
open(DATA, "+>file.csv") || die "Couldn't open file file.csv, $!";
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new();
if ($input == 19){ 
    my $status = $csv->print (\*DATA, \@{[%hash1]});
}
elsif ($input == 11){
    my $status = $csv->print (\*DATA, \@{[%hash2]});
}
close(DATA) || die "Couldn't close file properly";
```

I have went through numerous questions in Stack Overflow and Perl Monks, but I somehow haven't been able to figure out the solution to this without using `Text::CSV::Slurp`.

Please help.

P.S: `%hash1` and `%hash2` are simple hashes which have basic key-value pairing, and are not hash of hashes as of now. However, as the code develops, I may have to implement the logic on HoH as well.

Comment: You don't have an array of hashes, so Text::CSV::Slurp isn't really the right tool, anyway.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: I'm using `@{[%hash2]}` instead to declare it as array of hash and then de-reference it. In any case `$csv->print` doesn't accept anything but array de-reference.

Comment: Text::CSV::Slurp converts a single hash reference to a single CSV row. You are trying to convert a single hash reference into multiple CSV rows. Even if you put your hash in an array like that, Text::CSV::Slurp won't split it into multiple rows; that's not what it's designed for, so it's not the right tool for the job.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thanks for the tip. Looks like I got what I was searching for. This information is handy. Will try keeping this in mind from next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading you right, something like this is what you're after:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $VAR1 = {
          '2015-12-09 10:49:00' => '750 mW',
          '2015-12-09 10:49:02' => '751 mW'
        };
        
my $csv = Text::CSV -> new ( { sep_char => "\t", eol => "\n", binary => 1 } );
foreach my $key ( sort keys %{$VAR1} )  {
    $csv -> print ( \*STDOUT, [ $key, $VAR1 -> {$key} ] );
}
```

(Or if you're doing it with a hash, not hash ref):

```
foreach my $key ( sort keys %hash ) { 
     $csv -> print ( \*STDOUT, [ $key, $hash{$key} ] );
}
```

Note - this is explicitly sorting, because hashes are unordered. You look to be using an sortable date format, so this should be ok, but you *may* need to parse a data to an epoch and parse based on that.

### Output

```
"2015-12-09 10:49:00"   "750 mW"
"2015-12-09 10:49:02"   "751 mW"
```

Note - TSV embeds quotes because the fields contain spaces. You can remove those by:

```
my $csv = Text::CSV -> new ( { sep_char => "\t", 
                               eol => "\n", 
                               binary => 1, 
                               quote_char => undef } );
```

I would strongly suggest not using `DATA` as your output filehandle, as it's used already in `perl`. In fact, I would suggest using lexical filehandles with 3 arg `open`:

```
open ( my $output, '>', 'file.csv' ) or die $!;

# ...

$csv -> print ( $output, ### everything else
```

Comment: Thanks a million for the answer. I just tweaked it a little to match my requirements. Upvoted and Accepted your answer.